# CKShare and SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, cloudkit

Thank you for taking the time to read this post. I am pretty new to coding, so maybe my issues trying to implement **CKShare** with **SwiftUI** are due to a basic concept understanding, but I have been working on this for a few days and I can´t figure it out on my own.

I have checked this: ["SwiftUI and UICloudSharingController hate each other"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59230784/swiftui-and-uicloudsharingcontroller-hate-each-other), but I couldn't implement the solution suggested, perhaps because I started directly on SwiftUI and I do not understand how Swift works well enough.

I would like to share a **CKRecord** on a **custom zone** of a user's **private database**. I would rather not use Apple's standard screens for adding and removing people (**UICloudSharingController**) as I found it doesn't match with my users' natural journey.

I coded the lines below to *User1* to create a **CKShare** and include as participants the **CKUserIdentit** of *User2*. I then captured the **url** for *User2*, so they can accept the share.

On the Cloudkit dashboard, I can see the "**cloudkit.share**" type record on the *User1*'s private database. *User2* does appear on the **Sharing Participants** Field as **Type: User** and **Acceptance: Invited**.

However, once *User2* opens the url on a browser as an iCloud registered user, the following **error** is shown:

> iCloud has stopped responding
>
> REPORTED ERROR TITLE A non-empty string is required.
>
> REPORTED ERROR TYPE UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
>
> ERROR CONTEXT undefined

Has anyone dealt with something similar before? Is there any other way to include a known app's user on a **CKShare**?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Here my code:

```
let share = CKShare(rootRecord: recordEquipo)
share[CKShare.SystemFieldKey.title] = "Equipo" as CKRecordValue?
share[CKShare.SystemFieldKey.shareType] = "Some type" as CKRecordValue?
let fetchParticipantsOperation: CKFetchShareParticipantsOperation = CKFetchShareParticipantsOperation(userIdentityLookupInfos: [CKUserIdentity.LookupInfo(emailAddress: DTMemail)] )
fetchParticipantsOperation.fetchShareParticipantsCompletionBlock = {error in
    if let error = error {
        print("error for completion" + error.localizedDescription)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
}
fetchParticipantsOperation.shareParticipantFetchedBlock = {participant in
    participant.permission = .readWrite
    share.addParticipant(participant)
    let modifyOperation: CKModifyRecordsOperation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: [recordEquipo, share], recordIDsToDelete: nil)
    modifyOperation.savePolicy = .ifServerRecordUnchanged
    modifyOperation.perRecordCompletionBlock = {record, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("error for completion" + error.localizedDescription)
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
    modifyOperation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = {records, recordIDs, error in
        guard let ckrecords: [CKRecord] = records, let _: CKRecord = ckrecords.first, error == nil else {
            print("error in modifying the records " + error!.localizedDescription)
            completion(.failure(error!))
            return
        }
        if (share.url != nil) {
            completion(.success(share.url!))}

    }

    baseDatosPrivada.add(modifyOperation)
}
contenedor.add(fetchParticipantsOperation)
```

Comment: I found where the issue was, finally!
The url was created correctly but it needed to be opened using UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: url)!)